# Networking without network manager

Tags: networking

If I were to, for educational purposes, delete network manager on ubuntu 22.04 and try to configure wifi, ethernet, usb tethering and VPNs manually.

What would I need to have installed and how would i set it up?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. Figure out what Network Manager does, and what the programs it calls do, and figure out how you could do the same. The only thing that you would learn from "for educational purposes, delete `network manager`" is "Don't Do That".

Comment: I think you could do ethernet and wifi pretty easily with netplan.

Comment: I was thinking more along these lines: I will install any package necessary to achieve the same output. I was thinking about wpa_supplicant and dhcpcd but I don't know if that can cover everything on the list

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server does not use *Network Manager* so it's not required; though if you're starting with a Desktop system (*You didn't specify!*) then you're using a system that was configured for it.

Comment: You guys are such a buzzkill . I'm simply asking you the following: if there were no network-manager how would you setup your networking stack on ubuntu

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/configuring-networks/11876  Netplan is the default for Ubuntu Server, with changes in coming Desktop releases too (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue796#Testing_Netplan.2BIBk-s_Desktop_integration_with_NetworkManager).  If you install a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system that doesn't include *Network Manager*, Netplan.io is what is installed on it - you didn't mention any Ubuntu 22.04 LTS *product* details; just the release (22.04).

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the answer I was looking for was: wpasupplicant + dhcpcd5

I configured my networking stack using just those two and all of the above worked automatically while network-manager was stopped and disabled.